# General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint on tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, artisan-migrate

I have been trying out all possible solutions based on other stack questions and answers but I'm still not getting any success so I  had to make my own question.

I have the following Schemas

```
Schema::create('file_data', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->increments('id');
```

......

```
        Schema::create('claims', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
         ....
            $table->integer('file_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->default(DB::raw('NULL'));

          ....
            $table->foreign('budget_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('budgets')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

        });

        Schema::create('claims_details', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
           .........
            $table->integer('file_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->default(DB::raw('NULL'));
          ..........

        });
```

In another file

```
Schema::table('claims', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->foreign('file_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('file_data')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
      });

      Schema::table('claims_details', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->index(['invoice_date','claim_id']);
        $table->foreign('claim_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('claims')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('file_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('file_data');
      });
```

when I run the command `php artisan migrate` I get the following error

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>     SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `claims` add constraint `claims_file_id_
>     foreign` foreign key (`file_id`) references `file_data` (`id`) on delete cascade)

- The tables are Innob
- The columns are of the same type
- the columns are unsigned
- the files run in the correct order
- The only difference is that file_id needs to be null( they have to be)

---

Is it because the column is "null" makes it fail? I tried it without it being null and still failed. What are other causes that can cause it to have this issue?

Comment: `file_id` being nullable is fine in terms of foreign key constraints.  I'm wondering why your foreign key references `file_data.id` though, and not `files.id`.  Could it be that there is a 1-to-0/1 relationship between `files` and `file_data`?

Comment: If you can remove the data first before creating a foreign key i think it's work. Second option is, you must check if foreign key field value is exists with the primary key table value.

Comment: @reds Well the first option has been done as I am setting things up. Can you explain the 2nd option?

Comment: @e_i_pi it was a typo...sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I needed to have the columns indexed

Comment: Of course, one of the idiosyncricies of InnoDB! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6230588/foreign-keys-must-be-index-in-mysql